# YouTube Data API v3 - Get list of live streams ordered by concurrent viewers

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm working with the YouTube Data API and trying to figure out the correct call to make to get the data I'm after.

I want to retrieve a list of the currently active live streams, ideally by category, ordered by number of concurrent viewers. So far, I've only been able to get the liveStreamingDetails (which includes the concurrentViewers property) for a specific video ID.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the information I'm after with the current API? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This question has collected a lot of dust  I hope you managed to answer it by now 